# Computing the Jacobian of the Euler equations

Tags: multivariable-calculus, fluid-dynamics

Given the Euler equations

$$
\frac{\partial q}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial f(q)}{\partial x}=0,\qquad q=\begin{pmatrix}\rho\\\rho u\\\rho e\end{pmatrix}, \qquad f(q)=\begin{pmatrix} \rho u\\\rho u^2+p\\\rho u(e+\frac{p}{\rho})\end{pmatrix},
$$

where $e$ is the energy computed with
$$
e = \frac{1}{\gamma-1}\frac{p}{\rho}+\frac{u^2}{2},
$$
I have to compute the Jacobian matrix $J=\frac{df(q)}{dq}$. However, I have trouble to compute terms like

$$
\frac{\partial f_2(q)}{\partial q_2}= \frac{\partial \rho u^2}{\partial \rho u} = u + \rho u\frac{\partial u}{\partial \rho u}.
$$
The second term in the righthand side is unequal to 0, since if $\rho u$ changes, $u$ does not have to remain constant. However, I do not know how to continue from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably you need the Jacobian to solve a linearized approximation of the Euler equations.

The independent variables are $q_1 = \rho$, $q_2 = \rho u$, and $q_3 = \rho e$.

First, express pressure $p$ and all of the components of $f(q)$ in terms of the *independent* variables. Rearranging the equation-of-state, the pressure is given by

$$\begin{align}p &= (\gamma -1) \rho e - \frac{\gamma -1}{2}\rho u^2 \\ &= (\gamma -1) \rho e - \frac{\gamma -1}{2}\frac{(\rho u)^2}{\rho} \\ &= (\gamma -1) q_3 - \frac{\gamma -1}{2}\frac{q_2^2}{q_1}\end{align}.$$

The components of $f(q)$ translate to

$$\begin{align}f_1(q) &= \rho u \\ &= q_2  \\ f_2(q) &= \rho u^2 + p \\ &= \frac{q_2^2}{q_1} + (\gamma -1) q_3 - \frac{\gamma -1}{2}\frac{q_2^2}{q_1} \\  f_3(q) &= \rho u \left( e + \frac{p}{\rho}\right) \\ &= \frac{q_2 q_3}{q_1} + (\gamma -1) \frac{q_2q_3}{q_1} - \frac{\gamma -1}{2}\frac{q_2^3}{q_1^2}\end{align}.$$

Then find the partial derivatives with respect to $q_1$, $q_2$ and $q_3$  to compute the Jacobian.

For example,

$$\frac{\partial f_2(q)}{\partial q_2} = \frac{2 q_2}{q_1}- (\gamma -1)\frac{q_2}{q_1} = 2u - (\gamma-1)u.$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it helps out a lot! I was not sure if this was possible, since I thought that $q_1$ and $q_2$ were dependent on each other. They do both depend on $\rho$, that's what confused me (and still does a little). I will put some more thought into this.

Comment: @DaanvdWoude: You're welcome.  You just have to decide a priori on the independent variables.  One can allow $\rho$ and $\rho u$ to vary independently which now implies dependence of $u$ on $\rho$, etc.  However, in the end you have three degrees of freedom which can be expressed in various ways through combinations of variables.  For the purpose of linearizing the system of equations it does not matter.